# Line Integral - Why are these two integrals the same?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, line-integrals

I am starting to study calculus III and I came across the following situation

Given the following form $$ydx - xdy$$
Why the integral along the semicircle
$$P(t) = cos(t)\vec{i} + sin(t)\vec{j},\:0 \leq t \leq \pi$$
It is the same when using the following parameterization
$$y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq x \leq 1$$
Since the parameterizations are reversed?

When computing the first integral, I got $ - \pi $.

$$\int_c ydx - xdy$$
$$x = cos(t) \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt} = -sin(t)$$
$$y = sin(t) \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{dt} = cos(t)$$
$$\int_0^\pi ( sin(t)(-sin(t)) - cos(t)cos(t)) dt = -\pi$$

How do I compute the second one that has an inverted sense of integration than the first one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must know the orientation of the curve. In this case whether it is anti-clockwise or clockwise. That decides whether you go from $0$ to $\pi$ or $\pi$ to $0$ (similarly $-1$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $-1$).

$y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$

$dy = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx$

Please note that if we have anti-clockwise orientation as in your first integral then we go from $x = 1$ to $x = -1$. So the line integral is

$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{-1} (\sqrt{1-x^2} + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}) \ dx = -\pi$

Comment: Thanks @MathLover, your resolution solved all my doubts and helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome